# On an embedded system with no external input, can haveged provide entropy?

Tags: entropy, haveged

Take an example embedded system:

- Microprocessor
- Flash memory
- SDRAM

There is no UI and no network connection.

Can the [CPU timing jitter](http://www.chronox.de/jent/doc/CPU-Jitter-NPTRNG.pdf) that is used by [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) provide adequate true entropy to seed /dev/urandom?

Comment: i've collected such data from an ESP8266, which provides a cpu counter, and yes, you can collect entropy from such clock mis-matches. The quality isn't great, but it's good enough once whitened/hashed. the collection rate is slow as well, bps, not kbps.

Comment: Some embedded devices do offer HWRNG, use them,

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the exact system.

Haveged is highly dependent on the [rdtsc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) instruction. For the vast majority of embedded systems in production today this is going to be extremely difficult (to the point of effective impossibility) to estimate.

With a basic enough stripped out OS (or no OS) on a single core CPU where the execution of every line of code on the device is both predictable and independent of external state then it may be closer to realistically possible.

Although on a device with absolutely no external input (other than power up/down) i'm struggling to see the use case for an CSRNG?

Comment: Use case: you need to setup a WiFi AP to allow a mobile to connect to you so that you can receive WiFi credentials. That needs entropy before any entropy has been provided.

Comment: if you have wifi, you have a source of entropy from the network timings and signal strengths.

Comment: As @dandavis said. The WiFi adapter will provide all manner of interrupts. I'd suggest enabling it as early as possible in the boot sequence and setting the AP as late as possible.

Comment: Is there a branch of haveged that uses network timings and signal strengths for entropy?

Comment: Haveged by default represents network timings (and the associated jitter). The hardware causes interrupts which affect both the CPU cycle count and internal state. The internal state then has knock on on cycle rate across following instructions. All you need to do to include signal strengths is read them (via the CPU as opposed to DMA). This will run the data through the CPU again modifying its internal state.

Comment: Doesn't random.c also represent network timings by the same logic? The function add_interrupt_randomness should be impacted by the network. Therefore, what is the advantage of using haveged?

Comment: add_interrupt_randomness only measures the time between interrupts. Its also extremely costly to run - leading to dependence on it having been heavily reduced. Its only used once per second or per x interrupts. Haveged is influenced by interrupts knock on effect to processor state. There is also no additional cost in the way it reads this.
If you're going to drop to source level comparison you'd be better off fully reading the source and documentation of Haveged than posting here!

Comment: I've fully read the source of both. What I don't understand is where the line is that you should consider using haveged over the standard entropy gathering, and where the line is before even haveged is inadequate.

Comment: Haveged isn't designed to necessarily be more secure. Its designed to provide much more random data. It makes sense to use on systems where the standard tools do not provide entropy at the rate at which its consumed. This tends to be either heavy entropy consumers or headless systems (since standard tools lean heavily on user input).
Assuming you trust Havegeds model then it only becomes inadequate when it itself becomes the bottleneck on gathering entropy - at which point you would look for a High-Throughput Hardware True Random Number Generator.

Comment: The HAVEGE algorithm itself is questionable. This is even admitted by the authors of the original paper. It is better than nothing (at least if you write to `/dev/urandom` or so, rather than using the `RNDADDENTROPY` ioctl to increase the estimate count), of course.

Comment: @Hector Actually, `add_interrupt_randomness()` is called for every single interrupt. It has been this way for many years, since 2.4 or something. What it does is it mixes with a "fast pool" using a very simple mixing algorithm (Add-Rotate-XOR, see the `fast_mix()` function). Then once every 64 interrupts, the fast pool is mixed in with the main pool using `__mix_pool_bytes()`.

Comment: And haveged does _not_ measure network jitter. What it does is generate memory accesses in a loop which do not fit in the CPU cache and times how long the accesses take using `RDTSC`. The theory is that the timing of the MCH and DRAM modules is unpredictable enough that it can be used as a source of entropy. I suggest you read the paper on HAVEGE.

Comment: @forest - I'm on mobile and away from a computer until Monday so can't really fact check. From memory and my current understanding the algorithm is heavily dependent on rtdsc which would be changed by every system interrupt including networking events - which in turn will be influenced by jitter on all hardware. Years ago I read the HAVAGE paper but from what I understand haveged has diverged notably from this. Since you are talking about changes in versions I can only assume your knowledge of the actual code is drastically better than my own.

Comment: Yeah you're right that it is affected by interrupts, but that's not the primary source of entropy. It should be able to (theoretically) provide at least some entropy even on an idle system with interrupts disabled. And since a (modern) Linux kernel takes into account every interrupt anyway, even moreso than haveged can since it also takes into account EIP/RIP, the current register state, and the IRQ number, the idea of haveged using interrupts as its sole or primary source of entropy is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes of course. You will not have huge amount of entropy, but usually you *don't need* huge amounts anyway.

First, CPU and memory run at different frquencies, with different timers. Different timers always, necessarily mean that they will eventually diverge and the divergence will eventually be measurable at every desired scale. You can observe this by dropping two ping-pong balls on a table, or by watching the turn signals of two cars at a traffic light. Even when they seem to be in perfect sync at a time, you only need to wait a few seconds, and they will be entirely out of sync. Eventually, an operation will take a cycle longer than it should.

Second, and more importantly, SDRAM has refresh cycles (about 15 times per second) during which the currently being-refreshed row cannot be read for some 3-4 cycles. This necessarily means that reading from memory (or writing) does not always take *exactly* the same time at all times and at all addresses.

In summary, this means that no matter what, the same identical code running on two identical computers, and even on the very same computer will not always take exactly the same time, even if everything else is 100% identical and there are no external sources. If your timer is of high enough resolution (and rdtsc sure is), you can measure this.

Similar applies to flash memory. Reading from flash memory is not 100% deterministic either, but writing to it even less so. The controller may have to flash a deleted block (which is much larger than the sector size) and partially copy an existing block, then write the data you want to write. This involves a variable (and, although not true random, unpredictable) amount of data being copied, which obviously takes a different time every time.

Add to that the fact that modern CPUs have hyperthreading and operating systems (well, most of them, usually) do some non-neglegible amount of multithreading. Hyperthreaded CPU cores share resources, some more and some less. It's quite possible that every now and then a particular sequence of operations takes a few cycles more than usual because the processor resource is in use by the hyperthread sibling. All in all, this is not 100% deterministic either.

Scheduling threads works with yet another timer. Yes, modern kernels are "tickless", but timeouts/waits which also invoke the scheduler, still work with a timer. Nowadays that'd probably be HPET, but it could as well be something much less reliable. In any case, it is *yet another* timer that is likely not (though possibly) in perfect sync with the CPU clock and that cannot possibly be in sync with *both* the CPU and RAM (since they're different speeds).

---

EDIT:
In reply to below comment by @MikeOunsworth regarding not being able to generate lots of strong TLS sessions:

Obviously, you do not have enough entropy to run a webserver with TLS, not with a satisfying amount of security anyway, if anything depends on it.
**However:** If you do such a thing (*if...* the question explicitly states: "no network"), then you can easily get more entropy from the network. Do timing on handshakes, measure NTP roundtrips and jitter, DNS response time, you get it.

For a "typical" embedded device that that isn't controlling a nuclear weapon which is connected to the internet, I daresay that if you have as few as 30-40 bits of true random, you're good to go. Nobody is *realistically* going to be able to exploit the generator, let alone try (it's not worth the trouble). Taking the Linux implementation as example, the best attack that e.g. determines the previous state from a known state has 2<sup>64</sup> complexity. Now, assume you *somehow* know the complete state (because you know the seed and exactly how many random numbers were pulled so far, good divination skills needed) except those 40 bits of true random which you obviously *cannot know*. That's 2<sup>104</sup> complexity, good luck. Do you really think *anyone* will invest such an amount of resources to break into a single one of your puny little embedded devices? Wow, those gotta hold something really, really valuable.

Now, given the parameters of the actual question: **Embedded system, flash storage, no UI, no network**, you do not have this problem in the first place. You are not going to initiate three dozen TLS sessions per minute, you do not need loads of true random all the time, so it's pointless to object to the fact that this wouldn't work well.

What do you need a strong RNG for on a device which isn't connected to a network and which has flash storage? Well, unless your device is supposed to be a *true random generator* (what's the flash storage for then?), then you're most probably going to encrypt your drive, what else could you do (there's not many choices, really!).
That's something that ideally needs 128 bits (256 bits in super paranoia mode) of entropy *once*. We're talking *once*, not once every second. This should be not too much of a challenge.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to -1. I'm not convinced that "...will not always take exactly the same time" implies that there's enough entropy to, for example, generate strong TLS sessions keys as often as you'll need them. Also not convinced that hyperthreading or kernels are relevant since the question was about microprocessors (think Arduino) which are often single-process systems with no OS to speak of.

Comment: The main problem with the question is the word **adequate**. What is adequate? But I slightly disagree with @MikeOunsworth: an embedded system probably won't create a lot of TLS sessions, so I am convinced that the amount of entropy is enough for most uses.

Comment: @ThoriumBR ... but what evidence are you using that it's enough? I'm not arguing that it isn't, I'm simply saying that this answer is completely hand-wavy about how much is generated vs how much is consumed in a typical embedded use-case. .... data plz

Comment: There is no data. The HAVEGE algorithm was designed to mitigate abuses of the blocking `/dev/random`. The paper does not provide any proof that there are no techniques to predict the output, and they explicitly mention this. It is _probably_ adequate, but who knows? Also, regarding SSDs being non-deterministic, does that apply even with a cache hit? Or do you mean solid state media on embedded devices that may not even have a cache?

Comment: What I mean is that if your system *needs* real random numbers, you will not use a cheap embedded system. In this case, buy a Quantis USB TRNG and plug it on your device (costs almost 1k USD). If you need to secure a weather station, IoT lamp, or whatever consumer-grade internet connected device, it will be enough entropy, because you will start few SSL sessions, and they are not that critical anyway.

Comment: Thing is, what do you typically in a not-absurdly-paranoid setting need in terms of true randomness? You need 128 bits once every few minutes or so, but even if you only have, say, 40-60 bits of true random (and apply proper mixing like /dev/random does) then it's _way enough_ except in the most tinfoil-hat cases. Few people are able to (realistically) exploit a good random number generator to begin with, but nobody will _realistically_ be able to exploit a RNG seeded with as few as 30-40 bits of true random... let alone _even try_ on an embedded device which isn't securing a nuclear weapon.

Comment: Fun fact: If you do precise timing on how long it takes an attacker to do a handshake etc. then an attacker attempting to break in indeed _adds entropy_ for free, since network latency, again, is not predictable to the microsecond. The RTT as well as jitter from your NTP servers is again such a thing you can easily harvest. Wait, did you say **there's no network** on that embedded device? Well, good news, in that case you need a lot less entropy _by definition_. No TLS. What can you possibly need? 128-256 bits in total to encrypt data on permanent store. No biggie.